# What to use to develop an application for a WinCE 6.0 device that has no .NET installed?

Tags: windows-ce

Programming tools? The device is a car's multimedia radio/gps using that old WinCE I just want to make a custom made application just yo myself

Comment: An old version of Visual Studio would probably have support + SDK API. Good look sorting out the tooling. Might be worthwhile to pick up a more modern DIY kit.

Comment: Depends on the version of Windows CE the device is running, and whether there is an SDK available for it

Answer (score -1):

You can use Visual Studio 2008.
http://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/windows-embedded-compact-sdk#install-windows-ce-60-sdk

You can try the standard SDK. However, WinCE can be customized, so your device may missing some components of the standard SDK

If you like .Net CF you may be able to install it on the device. Toradex provides a [.Net CF installer](http://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/.net-compact-framework-flash-installer) for their devices.
In your case, you would need to get Platform builder to get .Net framework from Microsoft.